# Using Storage with Ionic 2

Tags: local-storage, ionic2

I am trying to use the storage in Ionic 2 as the documentation shows:

[ionic storage ducumentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/)

```
    import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
// import {GlobalVars, getMyGlobalVar} from './global-vars';



export class User {
  token: string;

  constructor(token: string) {
    this.token = token
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    static get parameters() {
        return [[Http]];
    }

    constructor(public http: Http, storage:Storage) {
        this.http = http;
      this.storage = storage;
    }

  currentUser: User;
  public login(credentials) {
    // console.log(getMyGlobalVar())
    if (credentials.username === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        // At this point make a request to your backend to make a real check!
        // send username and password to server
        // save user auth token


                    var creds = {username:credentials.username, password:credentials.password}
                    this.http.post('http://someurl.com/api-token-auth/', creds).subscribe(data => {
            this.storage.set('1984_token', data.json().token);
                        let access = (true);
                        this.currentUser = new User(data.json().token);
                        observer.next(access);
                        observer.complete();

                    }, error => {
                let access = (false);
                        observer.next(access);
            }, () => {

                    });
      });
    }
  }


  public getUserInfo() : User {
    return this.currentUser;
  }

  public logout() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.currentUser = null;
      observer.next(true);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

It sais it cannot set property of undefined, so storage is undefined. Stprage is also imported in app.module and added as a provider. I am tying to store this in a provider.

```
Runtime Error
Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
Stack
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._this.http.post.subscribe.access [as _next] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:37296:34)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44390:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44339:22)
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44292:26)
    at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44256:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:54386:38)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9723)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:34819:37)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9659)
    at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7083)
Ionic Framework: 2.0.0-rc.5
Ionic Native: 2.2.11
Ionic App Scripts: 1.0.0
Angular Core: 2.2.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.2.1
Node: 4.4.4
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
```

I cant find any clear documentation how to use this

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^1.1.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "isango_mobile: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: just remove `this.storage = storage;` in your constructor

Comment: @AmruthLS depending on what version Harry is using, but that document is outdated. I assume Harry is using a version above RC.0, else he would've/should've mentioned it.

Comment: I just installed it, so its the newest.

Comment: please see the updated actual code

Comment: I would change your subscribe response to type Http Response. `.subscribe(data: Response)` and import Response from '@angular/http'

Answer (score 0):

In typescript you need to use `this` to access class variables.

```
export class MyApp {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {
    //this.storage = storage; this line is not required as you have set access specifier in constructor parameter.
  }
  foo () {
     this.storage.set('name', 'Max');
  }
```

Comment: I have it like that in my code, that was a typo in the quesiton. but that is not the problem

Comment: are you using sqlite plugin? and are you trying in browser or device?

Comment: yes i am, and in browser. the code is in a provider.

Comment: I added the package.json contents

Comment: you are using static get parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133901/discussion-between-harry-and-suraj).

Answer (score 0):

Ok i used like this and working for me.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

 constructor(
 private storage : Storage){}

 foo(){
    this.storage.set('name','Max');
 }
```

And no need of any change in `app.module`

Comment: Same error: error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, works fine for me in pages and logs my test token set in another page E.g.

```
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'
    ....

    export class AccountPage {

      settings: AppSettings;
      loading: any;

      constructor(public http: Http, public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage, private platform: Platform, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public authService: AuthService) {

      }

     ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.storage.get('token').then((token) => {
          console.log('token ' + token);
        });
        }
```

But I find it undefined in providers. Using 'public storage: Storage' in constructor for both to inject Storage and then this.storage to get / set.

I'm handling Storage the same way for pages & providers, but no joy using providers. Have Storage added in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RVCommunityApp,
    AccountPage,
    DirectoryPage,
    FaqPage,
    ModalPage,
    OffersPage,
    OfferDetailsPage,
    QRCodePage,
    TabsPage,
    TouchpointsPage,
    TouchpointDetailsPage,
    VendorPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(RVCommunityApp, {
      tabsPlacement: 'bottom',
      statusbarPadding: true,
      tabSubPages: true,
      platforms: {
        ios: {
          statusbarPadding: true
        }
      }
    }, {}),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    RVCommunityApp,
    AccountPage,
    DirectoryPage,
    FaqPage,
    ModalPage,
    OffersPage,
    OfferDetailsPage,
    QRCodePage,
    TabsPage,
    TouchpointsPage,
    TouchpointDetailsPage,
    VendorPage
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, CategoryService, ConnectivityService, ContentService, DirectoryService, ModalService, OffersService, TouchpointService, AppSettings, Storage]
})
export class AppModule {}
```